# RMSE range value

Tags: expected-value, rms

Do RMSE value has range? For ex: If I have RMSE value 2,25   so what does it means? I did study case for An automatic Correcting essay system. I used RMSE to calculate accurate system value.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, RMSE can be between 0 and positive infinity. You interpret it as the square root of the mean squared deviation. So it is similar to the mean deviation but will be more influenced by larger deviations than by smaller ones. If you want more straightforward interpretation, look at mean absolute error (MAE) which will have the original measure’s units. Note as well that both RMSE and MAE are often normalized by dividing them by something like the measure range, mean, or standard deviation. This may help further with interpretation. For example MAE normalized by the range would be the average deviation in terms of percent of the range.